# find_element return only the first element selenuim?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is part of the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("link")
wait_page_to_load()
scroll_all_the_down()
comment_elems = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content-text"]')
len(comment_elems)#=1
```

the two function in the middle is working just fine I can see all the comments and I did verify the path but the find element is returning only the first element
I try this

```
comment_elems = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content-text"]')
```

but I need one with all elements.

Answer (score 1):

To find multiple elements use `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content-text"]')`
details here https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: i was searching for half an hour for missing s ty man i really appreciat it